# Sum of series $\sum n(\frac23)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} n\left(\frac23\right)^n$$

I've no idea what to do with it. If there is no n before fraction, it would be simply sum of convergent geometric series.

Comment: A tip: http://wolfr.am/14jypMb

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) very similar question.

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Arithmetico-geometric_series

Answer (score 11):

Recall that for $\vert x \vert < 1$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \dfrac1{1-x}$$
Differentiating both sides, we get that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} = \dfrac1{(1-x)^2}$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^{n} = \dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
Take $x=2/3$ to get what you want.